# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first on table create

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to create a Table that automatically dups its rows to show info from a Mysql table, however, I keep receiving this error, and i don´t know why.

```
 public void readTable(){

    View registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row_monitor, null, false);
    URLFETCHTABLE = URL + customerId;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URLFETCHTABLE,
            null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("ticket");
                for(int i = 0; i<=jsonArray.length() - 1; i++){

                    Log.d("valueOfI", String.valueOf(i));
                    Log.d("ARRAYLENGTH", String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    TextView ticketId = registro.findViewById(R.id.ticketId);
                    TextView truckPlates = registro.findViewById(R.id.truckplates);
                    TextView ecoTruck = registro.findViewById(R.id.ecoTruck);
                    TextView status = registro.findViewById(R.id.status);
                    View editar= registro.findViewById(R.id.checkButtons);

                    ticketId.setText(jsonObject.getString("ticketId"));
                    truckPlates.setText(jsonObject.getString("truckPlates"));
                    ecoTruck.setText(jsonObject.getString("ecoTruck"));
                    status.setText(jsonObject.getString("idStatus"));
                    editar.setId(jsonObject.getInt("ticketId"));
                    tbUsuarios.addView(registro);

                    iCount = i;
                }
                Log.d("iCount", String.valueOf(iCount));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("ARRAYLENGTH", "ENTRO AL CATCH");

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

I want to send the id of ticket to view editar, so that i can use it as a button to check the detail of the ticket, using the id to fetch all its details on mysql db

Comment: You are adding the same view (`registro`) to `tbUsuarios` multiple times since you call `addView` inside the for loop on the same view. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to add multiple `R.layout.table_row_monitor` views I think you should move the `View registro = LayoutInflater....` line to inside the for loop too (right after `JSONObject jsonObject =...`).